# How can i link 2 classes in python such that an object belonging to a class also has attributes from the other class?

Tags: python, class

I have to create a list of students. Each student has personal info(name date of birth, etc.), grades(math, English, science) and I need to only print out students who have a grade in math higher than the one in English but lower than the one they have in science. I created the classes but I'm having a little bit of trouble because the personal info, date of birth and grades have to be all different classes.
[image]

This is that I have for the classes, they are in order: `personal_info`, `date_of_birth` and `grades`

Comment: one thing i thought of was trying to create an object that would be part of the student class but also have attributes from all 3 classes, problem is I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: Please post code as text, not as image.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self):
        self.date = date_of_birth
        self.grades = grades()
        # And so on

s = Student()
s.date.function_in_birth_class()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you definitely need all 3 classes. By data-object relationship all information related to the Student class can be a self.property. This way when you create an instance of a Student you just pass to the construtor all the data and use conditional statements to print out the Students that meet your criteria.

Alternatively if for some reason you want to keep all 3 separate (don't recommend it) as you have done so far you can instantiate the 3 classes and inject them to the constructor of the Student class like:

```
names = Names(name='John', surname='Dowe')
date_of_birth = DateOfBirth(day=1, month=1, year=1970)
grades = Grades(math=1, english=2, science=3)

class Student(names, date_of_birth, grades)
    def __init__(self):
        self.names = names
        self.date_of_birth = date_of_birth,
        self.grades = grades

    def am_i_eligible():
        if (self.grades.english < self.grades.math < self.grades.science):
        print("First research and read documentation, then check university of youtube, then ask someone to make your homework.")

new_student = Student(names, date_of_birth, grades)
print(new_student.grades.math)
print(new_student.names.name)
print("Never post question as screenshot and do the effort to translate it to english so variable names are meaningful to us.")

new_student.am_i_eligible()
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i need to keep all 3 classes, i know this is not optimal because it just over complicates stuff, however the problem specifies that the 3 classes have to be there

Comment: I am glad that this helped you, I strongly recommend to fix your question so its up to the community standards, mark the above post as valid answer and visit on youtube Giraffe Academy's python OOP course :)